# Can we launch website on LUMA theme magento-2.2.4?

Tags: magento2.2.4, luma-theme

We are working on `Magento-2.2.4` community version.

We'd like to use the `default` **LUMA** theme for the development as of now. We have completed the website and it is ready to launch.

Suddenly, we have fixed to continue on and want to launch our website on LUMA theme.

If we launch website on LUMA theme, Will make any problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by `default Luma theme` ? if you mean by the default luma theme, the origine one that is installed in Magento it's **good** for one case and **not** in another !

If you have used that Luma theme without any customisation (what it surprises me), yes you can and there is no problem **BUT**, if you did some customisations, `css`, `js`, `layout`, `templates` etc... **YES** there is a problem and why ?

1. First of all if you did some customisations on a default one this means that you have updated the Magento core files and it's **forbidden**.
2. You didn't apply the Magento Theme inheritance. See [Magento DevDocs.](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html)
3. The most dangerous one is the day you update your Magento version (if Magento made updates in this theme), you will lose all your modifications and that's among the goals to override the theme.

**So** be nice, override the Magento theme in : `app/design/frontend/Luma/luma-child` for example then put all your customisations in this new one and give back the old as it was.

Good luck.

Comment: You're welcome, good luck !

Comment: @Prince, I have created the new theme folders as per the available tutorials of custom theme development. I chose my cutom theme to my website from admin panel also. How can i use the luma themes css files into my custom theme?